# Django - generically linking to a specific URL

Tags: django

Is there a generic way to link within Django to a specific URL?

For example I'll use the [writing your first Django app](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/intro/tutorial03/) if my urls.py looks like the example in the tutorial:

```
from django.conf.urls import url

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    # ex: /polls/
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    # ex: /polls/5/
    url(r'^(?P<question_id>[0-9]+)/$', views.detail, name='detail'),
    # ex: /polls/5/results/
    url(r'^(?P<question_id>[0-9]+)/results/$', views.results, name='results'),
    # ex: /polls/5/vote/
    url(r'^(?P<question_id>[0-9]+)/vote/$', views.vote, name='vote'),
]
```

I want to have a link to the 5th poll I could write the html

```
<a href='/polls/5/'>link</a>
```

But I'd rather write something like the below so I can maintain the specific URL from a single place:

```
<a href='{% url poll5 %}'>link</a>
```

I assume Django can do this but I'm not sure of the syntax or where to record the url

Comment: Almost exactly what you assume [exists in Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/templates/builtins/#url).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use namespaces in urls, in your project urls.py:

```
url(r'^polls/', include('polls.urls', namespace="polls")),
```

And then, in your template:

```
<a href='{% url 'polls:detail' 5 %}'>link</a>
```

The `5` can be poll.id or some of your variables.

Comment: Thanks, this worked a treat. in my proj I was using a word so had to use 

    <a href='{% url 'polls:detail' 'blah' %}'>link</a>

Answer (score 1):

you can write `<a href='/polls/5/'>link</a>` as

```
<a href='{% url 'details' question.id %}'>link</a>
```

or

```
<a href='{% url 'polls:details' question.id %}'>link</a>
```

if you namespace the polls url